# Beamer: in top-aligned columns with images, one of the images is lowered, not top-aligned

Tags: beamer

I am confronted with a very puzzling behavior of Beamer. The following minimal example contains four columns, each with an image (using the `figure` environment).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\graphicspath{{./Images/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[t]

\column{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3.2cm]{Epicurus}
\end{figure}

\column{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3.2cm]{Nietzsche}
\end{figure}

\column{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3.2cm]{Deleuze}
\end{figure}

\column{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3.2cm]{Badiou}
\end{figure}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like the images to be top-aligned, so I am using the option `[t]` on the `columns` environment. I am getting the following result:

[image]

Columns 1, 2, and 4 are indeed top-aligned, but the image in column 3 is lowered.

Looking for a solution to this problem, I read in one post that using the option `[T]` rather than `[t]` might help. So I tried that. And it indeed improves the situation. Now the image in column 3 is *almost* top-aligned, but only almost. I am not sure whether this is visible without zooming in, but image 3 is still a little bit lower than the other images:

[image]

What is going on here? Why does Beamer treat image 3 differently? The code is exactly the same as for the other images, and the image is also similar to the other images (they are all in format jpg).

Comment: The first step is to put an `\fbox` around each image (`\fboxsep=0pt`) to see if there is any extra white space.

Comment: I added `\fbox` around the images (i.e., around `\includegraphics`). The result is that the frame of image 3 sticks to the image. That is, the frame of image 3 is not top-aligned with the frames of the other images.

Comment: Picture 3 is wider than the other pictures.  Try using `\makebox[\columnwidth][c]{\includegraphics...}`.  It's beamer, who knows what will happen?

Comment: Thank you! `\makebox[\columnwidth][c]{\includegraphics...}` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this beamer configuration, the width of the frame is 307.3 points. The available width of each column is then 76.82pt

If an image is wider (first row, image `c`, 76.9pt !), it scrolls down, for reasons I don't know.

If all images exceed this critical value (all images in the second row), they will look aligned, but only because they all moved down.

This can be seen in the third row, equal to the second row, except for the width of image `b`, now 76.8pt, so is the only one that stays in the right place.

The **why** remains an open question.

[image: c]

```
The package multicol behaves more predictable.
```

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{./Images/}}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[t]          
    \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=76.8pt]{example-image-b}
    \end{figure}            
    \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=76.8pt]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}            
    \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=76.9pt]{example-image-c} % 76.8pt is OK
    \end{figure}            
    \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=76.8pt]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}            
\end{columns}       
76.8pt \hfill 76.8pt \hfill \textbf{76.9pt} \hfill 76.8pt
\begin{columns}[t]      
    \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=77pt]{example-image-b}
    \end{figure}        
    \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=77pt]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}        
    \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=76.9pt]{example-image-c}
    \end{figure}
    \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=77pt]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}        
\end{columns}
77pt \hfill 77pt \hfill 76.9pt \hfill 77pt
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Frame width =\the\framewidth
    \begin{columns}[t]      
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=76.8pt]{example-image-b}
        \end{figure}        
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=77pt]{example-image-a}
        \end{figure}        
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=76.9pt]{example-image-c}
        \end{figure}
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=77pt]{example-image-a}
        \end{figure}        
    \end{columns}
    \textbf{76.8pt} \hfill 77pt \hfill 76.9pt \hfill 77pt   
    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
        
Using the package multicol and four columns
    
\begin{multicols}{4}    
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=76.8pt]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}            

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=77pt]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=76.9pt]{example-image-c} % 76.8pt is OK
\end{figure}            

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=77pt]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}        
\end{multicols}
        
76.8pt \hfill 77pt \hfill 76.9pt \hfill 77pt

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Using the package `multicol` works. The solution suggested by John Kormylo in the comment to my post (namely, `\makebox[\columnwidth][c]{\includegraphics...}`) also works.